# bindkey, arrow keys, windows version of tcsh

Tags: windows, tcsh

I have installed tcsh (www.tcsh.org) onto windows using the binary tcsh-6.18.00-x86.exe.gz at ftp://ftp.astron.com/pub/tcsh/

I am trying to use the arrow keys in the standard way (e.g. up arrow is the previous command in history, etc.)

bindkey does not recognize arrow keys, and I can't figure out how to bind arrow keys without using the pre-defined symbolic names such as "up" etc. I am running tcsh within consoleZ, but it does not work in a standard windows shell command window either.

When I type "bindkey", no arrow key assignments are shown. When I try the command:

```
bindkey -k up up-history
```

I get an error:

Invalid key name 'up'

I have lots of muscle memory invested in the arrow keys, which is why I am trying to resolve this.

Is there a newer version of tsch that resolves this error? Thank you. I am running Window 7 Professional.

This seems to be true for 6.16 also (x86). I've tried the x86 and x64 binary versions without success.

Thank you.

-Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my tcshrc:

```
bindkey -b N-up history-search-backward
bindkey -b N-down history-search-forward
bindkey -b N-right forward-char
bindkey -b N-left backward-char
bindkey -b N-del delete-char
bindkey -b N-ins overwrite-mode
bindkey -b N-1 which-command
bindkey -b N-2 expand-history
bindkey -b N-3 complete-word-raw
bindkey -b N-home beginning-of-line
bindkey -b N-end end-of-line

bindkey -b M-x e_copy_to_clipboard
bindkey -b M-y e_paste_from_clipboard
```

This fixes most keys, it also sets <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>x</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> to copy & paste, since that won't work otherwise.

Also see [this message](http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/tcsh/2013-May/004656.html) I sent to the tcsh mailinglist a while back.

Answer (score 0):

With the correct Google search, I found the answer here. The names of the keys are "N-up", "N-down", etc. rather than "up", "down", etc.

One uses the -b option, not -k.

http://mx.gw.com/pipermail/tcsh/2013-May/004657.html